# How to pass information in a Jenkins pipeline job

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy

My pipeline script is configed from SCM.  It has some limitation, for example, I can't use `hudson.model` in my groovy script.  What I'm doing is always trigger python scripts in my groovy scripts so that I can do more things.  Now, the problem is how can I share information among all of my python scripts.  From example, my groovy scripts are

```
node('node1') {
  bat 'python a.py'
}
node('node2') {
  bat 'python b.py'
}
```

a.py is retrieving information from a server, and those information will be used in b.py.  What would be the preferred way to share some information between a.py and b.py?

Comment: What information? Could it be provided as command line arguments when you invoke them? Or as environment variables? Does it change as either or both of them run?

Comment: changed my description.

Comment: Can `b.py` just import and use the functionality from `a.py`, rather than executing them separately? Why are they in separate nodes? Could you provide some more context?

Comment: If you had some common data to import / export in the Pythons scripts, why not just import / export to a JSON file or something like that. In each Jenkins stage you could stash / unstash the data files (see the pipeline steps stash / unstash). As others said, more context is needed.

Comment: what is the format of the returned information from a.py? (string, text, file, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this on my own.  Well, yes, my description is not accurate.  What I really wanted is to share information among stages and nodes.  I ended up using the http request plugin.